# cudamat install nvcc fail on ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, nvcc

I have a GPU instance running on EC2 and I'm trying to install cudamat.

I've downloaded a copy to my home directory:

> git clone https://github.com/cudamat/cudamat

Then I cd into that directory and run:
sudo pip install .

Error is "command 'nvcc' failed with exit status 1.

Heres the full message:
    Unpacking /home/ubuntu/cudamat
       Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-s7db_8yv-build/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///home/ubuntu/cudamat
       PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    /tmp/pip-s7db_8yv-build

```
Installing collected packages: cudamat
  Running setup.py install for cudamat
    PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
/tmp/pip-s7db_8yv-build

    building 'cudamat.libcudamat' extension
    nvcc -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c cudamat/cudamat.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat/cudamat.o -O --ptxas-options=-v  --compiler-options=-fPIC
    error: command 'nvcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-s7db_8yv-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nulrhjnl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

/tmp/pip-s7db_8yv-build

running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/learn.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/cudamat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

running egg_info

creating cudamat.egg-info

writing cudamat.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing dependency_links to cudamat.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing top-level names to cudamat.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing manifest file 'cudamat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'cudamat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'cudamat.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

copying cudamat/cudamat.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/cudamat_kernels.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/learn.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/learn_kernels.cu -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

copying cudamat/rnd_multipliers_32bit.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

running build_ext

building 'cudamat.libcudamat' extension

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat

    nvcc -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c cudamat/cudamat.cu -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/cudamat/cudamat.o -O --ptxas-options=-v --compiler-options=-fPIC

    error: command 'nvcc' failed with exit status 1
```

There is something wrong with the path. since nvcc was not found.
heres when i type:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Anyone has an idea?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The error manifests itself only when sudo is used.

sudo changes the $PATH variable, depending on the security policy.

The problem is fixed if the following is used:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" pip3 install .
```

Answer (score 0):

nvcc is not configured for sudo access(i may be wrongly phrasing this sentence, but in short nvcc doesnt work with sudo)

there are two solutions to this problem:

- Give sudo access to nvcc(which you have mentioned) which may be the inefficient way.
- Don't use sudo while installing cudamat instead use the following command when you are inside the cudamat directory.

  `python setup.py install --user`

Note:

- While testing after installation dont use `import cudamat` from the cudamat directory which will through an error saying cudamat/cudamat not found.
- It will look in the local directory.
- Go to home and use `import cudamat` it will work

Answer (score 0):

Clone from github

```
git clone https://github.com/cudamat/cudamat.git
```

> This is only compatible with python 3